# Why does prestashop make 503 errors?

Tags: apache2, prestashop-1.6

I'm the system administrator of a website running on PrestaShop 1.6.1 | PhP 5.6 | MySQL 5.5 since the attempt to migrate our DB to a new server running on MariaDB 10.3 my site returns 503 errors randomly without any log(Apache / Mysql / Kernel Linux). The error is solved by restarting Apache2 on the server in Prod.
If anyone knows a monitoring service or command that could give me more information about this 503 error?

Answer (score 0):

503 error occurs when your web server is unable to get a proper response from a PHP script, so if the problem vanish after webserver restart it might probably depends from some misbehaving script / AJAX call or page that keeps PHP processes stuck over time.

If you PHP is handled by mod_php / mod_cgi you should be enable mod_status and should be able to have a detailed view of active - pending processes (you should keep track of them right after an Apache restart).

If your PHP is handled by php-fpm, you can use strace command to attach php-fpm pool and see workers and active processes :

```
strace -f $(pidof php-fpm | sed 's/\([0-9]*\)/\-p \1/g')
```

Comment: We switched from PhP FastCGI --> PhPFPM.

When we used your command, 503 errors appeared and we have to cancel it. When it's cancel our website works again instantly